# Yii 2 - Trying to login, but return as a guest again. How to solve this?

Tags: php, database, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I try to login using a custom User model, but when I try to login, it keeps me as a guest. I mean, when I click on the Login button in the `login.php` view, it returns to the home page, but still as a guest, and not a logged user. I don't know if I get problems with the cookies or anything else. I need help, please.

This is my custom User model, named `Usuario.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Usuario extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{

    public $authKey;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'usuario';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['rut', 'nombre', 'aPaterno', 'aMaterno', 'password', 'correo', 'direccion', 'telefono', 'idPerfil'], 'required'],
            [['idPerfil', 'idSesion'], 'integer'],
            [['rut', 'telefono'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['nombre', 'password', 'correo'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['aPaterno', 'aMaterno'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['direccion'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
            [['idPerfil'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Perfil::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['idPerfil' => 'idPerfil']],
            [['idSesion'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Sesion::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['idSesion' => 'idSesion']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'rut' => 'Rut',
            'nombre' => 'Nombre',
            'aPaterno' => 'A Paterno',
            'aMaterno' => 'A Materno',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'correo' => 'Correo',
            'direccion' => 'Direccion',
            'telefono' => 'Telefono',
            'idPerfil' => 'Id Perfil',
            'idSesion' => 'Id Sesion',
        ];
    }

    public function getIdPerfil0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Perfil::className(), ['idPerfil' => 'idPerfil']);
    }

    public function getIdSesion0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Sesion::className(), ['idSesion' => 'idSesion']);
    }



    public static function findIdentity($rut)
    {
        return self::findOne(['rut' => $rut]);
    }


    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new yii\base\NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    public static function findByUsername($rut)
    {
        return self::findOne(['rut' => $rut]);
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->rut;
    }

    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

This is the `actionLogin()` function in `SiteController.php`

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

And this is my `LoginForm.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $rut;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['rut', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = Usuario::findByUsername($this->rut);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see login page again, this row returns false:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
```

So, before this line, try to validate and check content of **errors** member:

```
if(\Yii::$app->request->isPost)
{
    $model->validate();
    var_dump($model->errors);exit;
}
```

"If" enclosure is needed otherwise this block will be executed also the first time when use enter in login page.

Comment: I got this error message when I try to login:
`array(2) { ["rut"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "Rut cannot be blank." } ["password"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "Password cannot be blank." } }`

I don't know why don't capture the data. Is there a problem in the model?