# Admin login is not working Yii 2 Advanced Project Template

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am working on a project using the Yii framework. I have upgraded the Yii version from 2.0.10 to 2.0.45, after upgrading the Yii the Admin login page (backend) is not working, It redirects to the login page again and again. (I am using dektrium library for login).

Server: Nginx

PHP:    7.4.13

It seems that session is not generating properly.
Here is the data in the session file: `__flash|a:0:{}`

And in the older version of Yii, the session file contains:
`__flash|a:0:{}__returnUrl|s:1:"/";__id|i:515;actions-redirect|s:1:"/";`

Also in **actionLogin** function in vendor\dektrium\yii2-user\controllers\SecurityController.php `$model->login()` is returning null.

Here is the configuration for the session in the backend directory:

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\rbac\components\DbManager',
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['info', 'trace', 'error', 'warning'],
                    'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/myfile.log',
                ],
            ],
        ],
]
```

Comment: This might be related [Upgrade from Yii 2.0.40](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-from-yii-2040)

Comment: I have checked, that also, But have not found any solution yet.

Comment: in ```login``` function in ```vendor\dektrium\yii2-user\models\LoginForm.php``` ```$this->user``` is returning null always.

Comment: Also i am getting the error as in ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045401/yii-2-trying-to-login-but-return-as-a-guest-again-how-to-solve-this```